# WCS 2.0.1 GetCoverage result size

Tags: wcs, getcoverage

Is there a parameter for WCS 2.0.1 `GetCoverage` requests which will sample underlying data and return a dataset of a particular size?

Similar to the `height` and `width` parameters in WCS 1.x.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCS 2.0 is devided into the core standard and extensions. See full list http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wcs. Changing the resolution requires Scaling extension https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/12-039 and control on interpolation Interpolation extension https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/12-049.

WCS 2.0 servers advertise in GetCapabilities which extensions they support. For example GeoServer supports both interpolation and scaling. You can read the details about usage from the standards but what makes the same effect as width and height is &SCALESIZE=E(600),N(400) where E and N are examples of the axis names. You must check the real axis names from DescribeCoverage.

Comment: Is there a known issue with GeoServer not working with `ScaleSize`? I have added it with the axisLabels provided by the `DescribeCoverage` document and continue to get `<ows:Exception exceptionCode="ScaleAxisUndefined" locator="i">
        <ows:ExceptionText>Scale Axis Undefined
[]</ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>`

Comment: There may be an issue. I had thought that this works `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&coverageID=sf__sfdem&SUBSET=E(589980,590000)&SUBSET=N(4913700,4923700)&SCALESIZE=E(200),N(200)` with one of the demo coverages but it yields the same error but I do not find any related issue from the GeoServer issue tracker.

Comment: Just found this very helpful post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rasdaman-users/SBA2SrVapHo/J8POkUVy-iwJ exactly what @user30184 mentioned but adds the complete URI for the axis. Using the complete URI has made the request successful.